# How to parse xml and get an vector for some attributes on an element

Tags: clojure

I know how to extract one attribute using zip-xml/attr, but how to extract multiple attributes?
e.g I have the following

```
<table>
  <column name="col1" type="varchar"  length="8"/>
  <column name="col2" type="varchar"  length="16"/>
  <column name="col3" type="int"  length="16"/>
<table>
```

And the expected result is. A silly way is to call zip-xml/attr for each  attribute, but is there any elegant way to do that?

```
[["co11" "varchar" 8] [["co12" "varchar" 16] [["co13" "int" 16]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to use a tree-walking function to extract the interesting data from the XML tree. clojure.walk has several of these, but here I use `tree-seq` from core clojure to just produce a seq of nodes and work on that. This function takes two functions - a `branch?` predicate which checks if a node can have children and a `children` function which gets them. I use `:content` for both, as tags with no nested tags produce nil, which is a falsey value and so it works also as a predicate.

```
(->> (clojure.xml/parse "res/doc.xml") ;;source file for your xml
     (tree-seq :content :content) ;; Produce a seq by walking the tree
     (filter #(= :column (:tag %))) ;;Take only :column tags
     (mapv (comp vec vals :attrs))) 
     ;;Collect the values of the :attrs maps into vectors 
     ;;and collect those into a vector with mapv
```

Your desired output had unmatched square brackets, but I assume it should be like

```
[["col1" "varchar" "8"] ["col2" "varchar" "16"] ["col3" "int" "16"]]
```

which was my return value. However, this is potentially brittle - you're relying on the maps returned by `clojure.xml/parse` preserving the ordering of the attributes in the XML in order to know what the data means. That's not really part of the contract of maps. As an implementation detail it creates [clojure.lang.PersistentStructMap](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/43cc1854508d655e58e377f84836ba128971f90c/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentStructMap.java)s which apparently *do* have this feature, but it might not always be so.
Alternatively you could use just `(mapv :attrs)` to keep the whole of the map in there.

Answer (score 1):

The right solution depends on how large and complex the XML is and to some extent, what you know about its structure. If it needs to be very generic, then you need to have quite a lot of logic to navigate the nodes etc. However, if it is a known format and you know what nodes you are interested in, its pretty straight-forward.

I used clojure.zip to create a zipper from the XML file and then use clojure.data.zip.xml to extract the nodes/paths I was interested in. I then defined simple helper functions to process specific nodes. This was pretty much my first bit of clojure and I've not yet gone back to it to re-factor it and refine/clarify some of my very rough clojure idioms based on what I've learnt since, but in the spirit of an example being worth 1000 words, here it is -

```
(ns arcis.models.nessus
  (:use [taoensso.timbre :only [trace debug info warn error fatal]])
  (:require [arcis.util :as util]
            [arcis.models.db :as db]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.xml :as xml]
            [clojure.zip :as zip]
            [clojure.data.zip.xml :as zx]))

(def nessus-host-keys [:hostname :host_fqdn
                       :system_type :operating_system
                       :operating_system_unsupported])

(def used-nessus-host-keys (conj nessus-host-keys
                                   :host_start :host_end
                                   :items :traceroute_hop_0 :traceroute_hop_1
                                   :traceroute_hop_2 :traceroute_hop_3
                                   :traceroute_hop_4 :traceroute_hop_5
                                   :traceroute_hop_6 :traceroute_hop_7
                                   :traceroute_hop_8 :traceroute_hop_9
                                   :traceroute_hop_10 :traceroute_hop_11
                                   :traceroute_hop_12 :traceroute_hop_13
                                   :traceroute_hop_14 :traceroute_hop_15
                                   :traceroute_hop_16 :traceroute_hop_17
                                   :host_ip :patch_summary_total_cves
                                   :cpe_0 :cpe_1 :cpe_2 :cpe_3 :cpe_4 :cpe_5
                                   :cpe_6 :cpe_7 :cpe_8 :cpe_9))

(def nessus-item-keys [:port :svc_name :protocol :severity :plugin_id
                       :plugin_output])

(def used-nessus-item-keys (conj nessus-item-keys
                                 :plugin_details
                                 :plugin_name
                                 :plugin_family))

(def nessus-plugin-keys [:plugin_id :plugin_name :plugin_family :fname
                         :script_version :plugin_type :exploitability_ease
                         :vuln_publication_date :cvss_temporal_data
                         :solution :cvss_temporal_score :risk_factor
                         :description :cvss_vector :synopsis
                         :patch_publication_date :exploit_available
                         :plugin_publication_date :plugin_modification_date
                         :cve :bid :exploit_framework_canvas :edb_id
                         :exploit_framework_metasploit :exploit_framework_core
                         :metasploit_name :canvas_package :osvdb :cwe
                         :cvss_temporal_vector :cvss_base_score :cpe
                         :exploited_by_malware])

(def used-nessus-plugin-keys (conj nessus-plugin-keys
                                   :xref :see_also :cert
                                   :attachment :iava :stig_severity :hp
                                   :secunia :iawb :msft))

(def show-unprocessed true)

(defn log-unprocessed [title vls]
  (if (and show-unprocessed
           (seq vls))
    (println (str "Unprocessed " title ": " vls))))

;;; parse nessus report
(defn parse-xref [xref]
  {:xref (first (:content xref))})

(defn parse-see-also [see-also]
  {:see_also (first (:content see-also))})

(defn parse-plugin [plugin]
  {(util/db-keyword (name (:tag plugin))) (first (:content plugin))})

(defn parse-contents [cont]
  (let [xref (mapv parse-xref (filter #(= (:tag %) :xref) cont))
        see-also (mapv parse-see-also (filter #(= (:tag %) :see-also) cont))
        details (reduce merge {}
                        (map parse-plugin
                             (remove #(or (= (:tag %) :xref)
                                          (= (:tag %) :see-also)) cont)))]
    (assoc details
      :see_also see-also
      :xref xref)))

(defn fix-item-keywords [item]
  (let [ks (keys item)]
    (into {}
          (for [k ks]
            [(util/db-keyword (name k))
             (k item)]))))

(defn parse-item [item]
  (let [attrs (fix-item-keywords (:attrs item))
        contents (parse-contents (:content item))]
    (assoc attrs
      :plugin_output (:plugin_output contents)
      :plugin_details (assoc (dissoc contents :plugin_output)
                        :plugin_id (:plugin_id attrs)
                        :plugin_family (:plugin_family attrs)))))

(defn parse-properties [props]
  (into {}
        (for [p props]
          [(util/db-keyword (:name (:attrs p)))
           (first (:content p))])))

(defn parse-host [h]
  (let [items (map first (zx/xml-> h :ReportItem))
        properties (:content (first (zx/xml1-> h :HostProperties)))]
    (assoc (parse-properties properties)
      :hostname (zx/attr h :name)
      :items (mapv parse-item items))))

(defn parse-hosts [hosts]
  (mapv parse-host hosts))

(defn parse-file [f]
  (let [root (zip/xml-zip (xml/parse (io/file f)))
        report-xml (zx/xml1-> root :Report)
        hosts (zx/xml-> report-xml :ReportHost)]
    {:report_name (zx/attr report-xml :name)
     :policy (zx/text (zx/xml1-> root :Policy :policyName))
     :hosts (parse-hosts hosts)}))

;;; insert nessus records into db
(defn mk-host-rec [scan-id host]
  (let [[id err] (db/get-sequence-nextval "host_seq")]
    (if (nil? err)
      (assoc (util/build-map host nessus-host-keys)
        :ipv4 (:host_ip host)
        :scan_start (util/from-nessus-date (:scan_start host))
        :scan_end (util/from-nessus-date (:scan_end host))
        :total_cves (:patch_summary_total_cves host)
        :id id
        :scan_id scan-id)
      nil)))

(defn insert-patches [p]
  (when (seq p)
    (db/insert-nessus-host-patch (first p))
    (recur (rest p))))

(defn insert-host-patch [id host]
  (let [p-keys (filter #(re-find #"patch_summary_*" %) (map name (keys host)))
        recs (map (fn [s]
                    {:id (first (db/get-sequence-nextval "patch_seq"))
                     :host_id id
                     :summary ((keyword (str "patch_summary_txt_" s)) host)
                     :cve_num ((keyword (str "patch_summary_cve_num_" s)) host)
                     :cves ((keyword (str "patch_summary_cves_" s)) host)})
                  (filter seq
                          (map #(second (re-find #"patch_summary_txt_(.*)" %))
                               p-keys)))]
    (insert-patches recs)
    (util/remove-keys host (map keyword p-keys))))

(defn mk-item-rec [host-id item]
  (let [[id err] (db/get-sequence-nextval "item_seq")]
    (assoc (util/build-map item nessus-item-keys)
      :host_id host-id
      :id id)))

(defn insert-item [host-id item]
  (let [rec (mk-item-rec host-id item)
        not-done (keys (util/remove-keys item used-nessus-item-keys))]
    (log-unprocessed "Item Keys" not-done)
    (db/insert-nessus-report-item rec)
    (:plugin_id item)))

(defn mk-plugin-rec [item]
  (let [rec (util/build-map (:plugin_details item) nessus-plugin-keys)
        not-used (keys (util/remove-keys (:plugin_details item)
                                          used-nessus-plugin-keys))]
    (log-unprocessed "Plugin Keys" not-used)
    (assoc rec
      :vuln_publication_date (util/from-nessus-date
                              (:vuln_publication_date rec))
      :patch_publication_date (util/from-nessus-date
                               (:patch_publication_date rec))
      :plugin_publication_date (util/from-nessus-date
                                (:plugin_publication_date rec))
      :plugin_modification_date (util/from-nessus-date
                                 (:plugin_modificaiton_date rec)))))

(defn insert-xref [plugin-id xrefs]
  (when (seq xrefs)
    (let [xref {:id (first (db/get-sequence-nextval "xref_seq"))
                :plugin_id plugin-id
                :xref (:xref (first xrefs))}]
      (db/insert-nessus-xref xref)
      (recur plugin-id (rest xrefs)))))

(defn insert-see-also [plugin-id see-also]
  (when (seq see-also)
    (let [sa {:id (first (db/get-sequence-nextval "ref_seq"))
              :plugin_id plugin-id
              :reference (:see_also (first see-also))}]
      (db/insert-nessus-ref sa)
      (recur plugin-id (rest see-also)))))

(defn insert-plugin [item]
  (let [rec (mk-plugin-rec item)
        xref (:xref (:plugin_details item))
        see-also (:see_also (:plugin_details item))]
    (if (seq xref)
      (insert-xref (:plugin_id rec) xref))
    (if (seq see-also)
      (insert-see-also (:plugin_id rec) see-also))
    (db/upsert-nessus-plugin rec)))

(defn insert-items [host-id items plugin-set]
  (if (empty? items)
    plugin-set
    (let [p (insert-item host-id (first items))]
      (if-not (contains? plugin-set p)
        (insert-plugin (first items)))
      (recur host-id (rest items) (conj plugin-set p)))))

(defn insert-host [scan-id host plugin-set]
  (if-let [h-rec (mk-host-rec scan-id host)]
    (let [[v err] (db/insert-nessus-host h-rec)
          items (:items host)]
      (if (nil? err)
        (let [host2 (insert-host-patch (:id h-rec) host)]
          (log-unprocessed "Host Keys" (keys (util/remove-keys
                                              host2 used-nessus-host-keys)))
          (insert-items (:id h-rec) items plugin-set))
        plugin-set))
    plugin-set))

(defn insert-hosts
  ([id hosts]
     (insert-hosts id hosts #{}))
  ([id hosts plugins]
     (if (empty? hosts)
       plugins
       (let [plugin-set (insert-host id (first hosts) plugins)]
         (recur id (rest hosts) plugin-set)))))

(defn mk-scan-record [id report]
  {:id id
   :name (:report_name report)
   :scan_dt (util/to-sql-date)
   :policy (:policy report)
   :entered_dt (util/to-sql-date)})

(defn store-report [update-plugins report]
  (let [[id err] (db/get-sequence-nextval "nscan_seq")
        scan-rec (mk-scan-record id report)]
    (if (nil? err)
      (let [[v e] (db/insert-nessus-scan scan-rec)]
        (if (nil? e)
          (if update-plugins
            (let [plugin-list (set (first (db/select-nessus-plugin-ids)))]
              [(insert-hosts id (:hosts report) plugin-list) nil])
            [(insert-hosts id (:hosts report)) nil])
          [v e]))
      [id err])))

(defn process-nessus-report [update-plugins filename]
  (let [report (parse-file filename)]
    (println (str "Report: " (:report_name report)
                  "\nPolicy: " (:policy report)
                  "\nHost Records: " (count (:hosts report))))
    (store-report update-plugins report)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Magos's answer using `tree-seq` is perfectly fine, but there's no reason to abandon zippers; filtering using zippers is more succinct and the arguably the "clojure" way. (note this example uses `data.xml` (`[org.clojure/data.xml "0.0.8"]`) instead of `clojure.xml`).

```
(require '[clojure.data.zip.xml :as zf])
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(def ex
"<table>
  <column name=\"col1\" type=\"varchar\"  length=\"8\"/>
  <column name=\"col2\" type=\"varchar\"  length=\"16\"/>
  <column name=\"col3\" type=\"int\"  length=\"16\"/>
</table>")

(let [x (z/xml-zip (clojure.data.xml/parse-str ex))]
  (->> (zf/xml-> x :column) ;;equivalent to (->> treeseq ... filter)
         flatten
        (keep :attrs)
        (map vals)))
;>>> (("col1" "varchar" "8") ("col2" "varchar" "16") ("col3" "int" "16"))
```

But the `xml->` macro simply applies functions in order, so you can do the following:

```
(let [x (z/xml-zip (clojure.data.xml/parse-str ex))]
  (->> (zf/xml-> x :column #(keep :attrs %))
       (map vals)))

;>>> (("col1" "varchar" "8") ("col2" "varchar" "16") ("col3" "int" "16"))
```